# Rails - bootstrap modal submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap modal which is a `bootstrap_form_for` form, which I want to create something.

So lets say I am on `/users/20`

And on that screen the user can create a `:thing` via the modal popup.  They click a button and the modal appears.  They fill out the form which creates a `:thing` such like:

```
/users/20/thing/1
```

Here is my routes:

```
  resources :users do
    resources :things
  end
```

My form looks like:

```
  <div class="modal-body">
    <%= bootstrap_form_for(:thing) do |f| %>
        <%= f.text_field :name %>
        <%= f.text_field :description %>
        <%= f.submit 'Save Thing', id: 'submit-thing', class: 'btn btn-primary'  %>
  </div>
```

However, on submit I get the following error:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/users/20"):
```

What am I missing?  How do I target the `user_things_path` which exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass path  like this then it should work.

```
url: post_path
  <div class="modal-body">
    <%= bootstrap_form_for(@thing, url: user_things_path(@user)) do |f| %>
        <%= f.text_field :name %>
        <%= f.text_field :description %>
        <%= f.submit 'Save Thing', id: 'submit-thing', class: 'btn btn-primary'  %>
  </div>
```

Comment: This looks good!  This seems to hit the create action on the things_controller.  How do I close the modal, via a JS.erb.?  Thanks!